# Is there a way to return multiple results from an DB2 SQL query?

Tags: sql, db2

Currently I have 4 tables that have a column called userid. Is there a way to write a single query that will return a 1 if the userid exist in the table or a zero if it does not exist?

```
An example of output would be if it exist in all tables:
if exist in TB1 = 1 
if exist in TB2 = 1
if exist in TB3 = 1 
if exist in TB4 = 1 
then returns = 1, 1, 1, 1

An example of output would be if it exist in 3 of the tables:
if exist in TB1 = 1 
if exist in TB2 = 1
if exist in TB3 = 0 
if exist in TB4 = 1 
then returns = 1, 1, 0, 1
```

Comment: You can still provide DDL for your source tables (or similar examples) and a definition of the expected output. Check out [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @3N1GM4, I have updated the question to show expected output

Comment: Your question is still not clear at all. Where is the `userid` being searched for specified? Do you really want a concatenated string output of comma-delimited booleans? Providing a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as previously requested would make your question a lot easier to answer, without all the guesswork.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to write a table user defined function

https://www.idug.org/browse/blogs/blogviewer?blogkey=1c83f8d0-6f2c-43c8-8125-bbe127d88f9e

If this does not work, you can also think about writing a scalar udf to check if a SINGLE table contains the id. In this the case you have to pass the tablename to the udf Afterwards you just call the udf for every table you need to check for.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

It's surprising not obvious how to return 0 if a row doesn't exist.

This, returns '1' if the row exists, but nothing if it does not.

```
select '1' from sysibm.sysdummy1 where exists(select * from tbl1 where userid = 'MyUser');
```

So you have to embed the above into a statement that will generate the zero in place of the null..

```
values coalesce((select '1' from sysibm.sysdummy1 where exists(select * from tbl1 where userid = 'MyUser'))
                ,'0');
```

As the other answer suggested, creating a User Defined Function (UDF), `RecordExists('MYTBL1','USERID','MyUser');`  may be worthwhile depending on how often you need such functionality.  But that's outside the scope of your question.

There's a couple of way to put together multiple checks, here's one.

```
values (coalesce((select '1' from sysibm.sysdummy1 where exists(select * from tbl1 where userid = 'MyUser'))
                ,'0')
       , coalesce((select '1' from sysibm.sysdummy1 where exists(select * from tbl2 where userid = 'MyUser'))
                ,'0')
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with 
  tb1 (userid) as (values 1, 1, 2)
, tb2 (userid) as (values 1, 1, 2)
, tb3 (userid) as (values 2, 2, 2)
, tb4 (userid) as (values 1, 1, 2)
select 
  coalesce ((select 1 from tb1 where userid=1 fetch first 1 row only), 0) c1
, coalesce ((select 1 from tb2 where userid=1 fetch first 1 row only), 0) c2
, coalesce ((select 1 from tb3 where userid=1 fetch first 1 row only), 0) c3
, coalesce ((select 1 from tb4 where userid=1 fetch first 1 row only), 0) c4
from sysibm.sysdummy1
```

| C1 | C2 | C3 | C4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/d2ZkNoUs)